# MULE 4 : Batch Process : How does the batch process component process records in a collection?

Tags: mule4

Scenario : I have  2 source database tables [ Student_INFO, Teachers_INFO] from where I will pull data using a Scheduler in every 1 hour.

STUDENT_INFO contains :

1. Student name
2. Student roll number
3. Subjects taken by the student for example MATHS, ENG, SCIENCE, ARTS

TEACHERS_INFO contains :

1. Teacher Name
2. Subject taught by the teacher for example MATHS

My expected output is to group against each teacher the students taught by him.
To do this, I want to

1. collect the data from the two sources
2. Create a map having teachers name as key and then iterate through students subjects and add them to the teacher map

Now I have the code ready using a for each loop n MULE 4

But I am unable to understand how to do the same in batch processing. Can someone please help me visualize the problem from MULE 4 batch processing scope?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your data too large that you need to process individual records asynchronously or are you doing anything else aside from grouping data? I was just thinking batch might not be the best solution for your scenario as it is more complex as compared to for-each or parallel-for-each. If you are just grouping datasets, I think this can be done by a single transform step and using dataweave. Anyway, to answer your question, you need to make sure that your payload is an array/collection before the batch scope. Inside batch scope, you need to create batch step to process individual member.

Comment: @oim Hello, I  am just giving the above scenario to understand few things : Since batch scope process element as individual records, if i have to do a tranformation of each  record in side the batch scope, do I use map method on the payload or do I apply transformation for a single record?

Comment: Once you are inside the batch scope, your "payload" will be the individual member. For example, you have a payload ["1", "2", "3"], and you have a batch scope to process individual member, your payload inside your batch step will be "1" for one instance, "2" for another and so on. Note that each step will be process independently and thus variables introduced when you process "1" will not be available when "2" is being processed.